# Input data in firebase to graph android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, graph

My database is like this from firebase [image: data]

I was figuring out how to combine this two as set1 and set2 on graph but the first problem I encounter is when I use the Date as x it must be in int.

```
gIncomeDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("IncomeData").child(uid);
gExpenseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ExpenseData").child(uid);
```

How can I convert the month into number where in I will use the number on x axis(1f) in here

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    ArrayList<BarEntry> values1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> values2 = new ArrayList<>();

        values1.add(new BarEntry(1f, 20));
        values2.add(new BarEntry(1f, 20));

    BarDataSet set1= new BarDataSet(values1,"Income");
    BarDataSet set2= new BarDataSet(values2,"Expense");
    BarData barData = new BarData(set1,set2);
    set1.setValues(values1);
    set2.setValues(values2);
    barinc.setData(barData);
```

And is it also possible to put the name of the months below them?
[image]

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to make use of the: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart for displaying the bar graph.

Once you retrieve the data from the Firebase database and update the chart:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // Get the data from the snapshot
    Map<String, Long> data = (Map<String, Long>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

    // Prepare the data for the chart
    List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : data.entrySet()) {
      entries.add(new BarEntry(index++, entry.getValue()));
    }

    // Create the chart
    BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "Data");
    BarData barData = new BarData(dataSet);
    BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.bar_chart);
    chart.setData(barData);
    chart.invalidate();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    // Handle errors
  }
});
```

Comment: I think the new BarEntry is not working because it keeps crashing y,x

Comment: Check if you are able to get the data from firebase database